# Nested Row Labels to Column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I  have a CSV that appears to be the output of an Excel Pivot Table with names nested as row labels for repeating groups. I would like to clean the data so that the row labels are repeated in a separate column, ideally using dplyr.

The data looks like this:

```
dd <- data.frame(variables = c("Abington", "Number of Sales","YTD Number of Sales","Median Sale Price","YTD Median Sale Price", "Acton", "Number of Sales","YTD Number of Sales","Median Sale Price","YTD Median Sale Price"), Year1 = c(" ", 16, 50,415000,413500," ",23,60,799900,704000), Year2 = c(" ",8,13,583000,575000," ",9,39,995000,800000))

dd

variables              Year1   Year2
Abington              
Number of Sales        16      8
YTD Number of Sales    50      13
Median Sale Price      415000  583000
YTD Median Sale Price  413500  575000
Acton              
Number of Sales        23      9
YTD Number of Sales    60      39
Median Sale Price      799900  995000
YTD Median Sale Price  704000  800000
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
Town          variables               Year1  Year2           
Abington      Number of Sales         16     8
Abington      YTD Number of Sales     50     13
Abington      Median Sale Price       415000 583000
Abington      YTD Median Sale Price   413500 575000          
Acton         Number of Sales         23      9
Acton         YTD Number of Sales     60     39
Acton         Median Sale Price       799900 995000
Acton         YTD Median Sale Price   704000 800000
```

Comment: If you own the pivot table you can show the table in tabular form and repeat item labels to get exactly the table you want, or are you looking for a solution in R specifically?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't own the pivot table - it's actually a PDF that was converted to a CSV using Tabula. I would be happy to use an Excel-based solution if you have one!

Comment: What is the logic for being able to identify the rows that should eventually be in the column `Town`. Could we say "anytime both Year 1 and Year 2 are NA, that is a Town"? I'm assuming there are more than just two towns in this pivot table.

Comment: You are correct, the real table is 1845 rows long with ~370 unique towns. And yes, that is a good point, we could say "anytime both Year 1 and Year 2 are NA, that is a Town."

Comment: are there always the same number of variables per town (like 4 in your example data?)

Comment: Great question, there is always the same number of variables per town.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` (or `dplyr` & `tidyr`) for this:

```
library(tidyverse)

dd %>%
  mutate(Town = ifelse(Year1 == " " & Year2 == " ", variables, NA)) %>%
  fill(Town, .direction = "down") %>%
  filter(Town != variables) %>%
  relocate(Town)
```

Resulting in:

```
      Town             variables  Year1  Year2
1 Abington       Number of Sales     16      8
2 Abington   YTD Number of Sales     50     13
3 Abington     Median Sale Price 415000 583000
4 Abington YTD Median Sale Price 413500 575000
5    Acton       Number of Sales     23      9
6    Acton   YTD Number of Sales     60     39
7    Acton     Median Sale Price 799900 995000
8    Acton YTD Median Sale Price 704000  8e+05
```

Important to note that the empty values at `Year1` and `Year2` are actually whitespaces (" ") rather than empty strings or NA.

Comment: Nice.. you can simplify the filter to just when `Town!=variables`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach:

```
bind_cols(
  tibble(Town=rep(filter(dd,is.na(as.numeric(Year1)))$variables, each=4)),
  filter(dd,!is.na(as.numeric(Year1)))
)
```

Output:

```
  Town     variables             Year1  Year2 
  <chr>    <chr>                 <chr>  <chr> 
1 Abington Number of Sales       16     8     
2 Abington YTD Number of Sales   50     13    
3 Abington Median Sale Price     415000 583000
4 Abington YTD Median Sale Price 413500 575000
5 Acton    Number of Sales       23     9     
6 Acton    YTD Number of Sales   60     39    
7 Acton    Median Sale Price     799900 995000
8 Acton    YTD Median Sale Price 704000 8e+05
```